# what is the good Protocol for File Transfert?

Tags: android, file-transfer

I would like To implements an Application to Transfer File Between Devices from one devices to  others in the some network. I know that their is many Protocol to transfer File (TCP (socket), UDP, DLNA ) . I need to choose one of this  protocol. but before I would like to know all this protocol.  So what i can  i use and what is the best way to transfer file?

Comment: which you can implement easily that is best

Answer (score 0):

I think FTP is the easiest and most common, but it is not secure.  If you are sending sensitive information, try SFTP or encrypt the files you're sending using PGP.